# Mat button toggle group component is not working

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, web-frontend, materialbutton

I am building an application which requires mat button toggle group (material component) and this is the code,

```
    <mat-button-toggle-group appearance="legacy" name="fontStyle" aria-label="Font Style">
        <mat-button-toggle value="bold">Bold</mat-button-toggle>
        <mat-button-toggle value="italic">Italic</mat-button-toggle>
        <mat-button-toggle value="underline">Underline</mat-button-toggle>
    </mat-button-toggle-group>
```

But, it's not displaying correctly. It's displaying like,

[image]

Could any one figure it out what's the problem?

Comment: Did you import all necessary materials modules? like ` import {MatButtonToggleModule} from '@angular/material/button-toggle';`

Comment: Yea, did in the module imports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import or define a [theme](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming) for angular material, add the following import to your styles.css

```css
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
```

Comment: Yea... It's working. But, I couldn't understand why it is working. Could you explain me?

Comment: angular material does not apply any styling by default, you either have to import any of the prebuilt themes like in the example, or define your own using scss.